# How to extract id from url in a query?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table with a column containing many urls like this one:

```
https://myshop.com/lv/buitine-technika-elektronika/virtuves-iranga/virduliai/virdulys-elektrinis-virdulys-forme-fkg-147?id=22031685
```

I want to **extract** the id from the URL, but I have no idea how to do this. I could easily do this in Python later using this `regex`:

```
\?id\=(\d+)
```

But I'd like to have as much of data prepared in my query before going to python if that is possible. I know how to use regex in MySQL `where` clause, but no idea how to use it anywhere else. Is there a way to do this?

ID length can be different and there might be something else after that...

Comment: Some tasks (such as this one) are better off done in the Client.

Answer (score 2):

If every URL would only ever have a single `id` query parameter, then we can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '?id=', -1) AS id
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

For a more general solution in MySQL 8+, we can use `REGEXP_SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(url, '^.*?.*id=([^&]+).*$', '$1') AS id
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The regex based approach can handle `id` appearing anywhere in the query string.

Comment: *ant there migth be something else after that...*

Comment: @BenM Pre MySQL 8+ can't really cope with that requirement in general, assuming the `id` could appear anywhere in the query string.  But, MySQL 8+ can using `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I believe that regexp_replace literally makes an edit in a database which I am not allowed to do

Comment: @milka1117 Running a `SELECT` query absolutely does _not_ alter any data in your table, regardless of which function gets called.

Comment: @Aurieli I don't think that MySQL 8's regex API supports lookbehinds (though I could be wrong).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah, sorry:)